# Использование C# Web Service (как я понял)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, wcf

Надо использовать сервис - http://ws.etsp.ru/PartsRemains.svc

Имеется .NET, установил PartsRemains.cs, output.config

Не прошу детального объяснения, хотя бы примерные советы, в какую сторону двигаться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет это не Windows Service, а Web Service.

Вам нужно к нему подключиться и вызвать его методы.

1. Для подключения [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В появившемся окне [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Введите адрес сервиса [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Далее по интсрукции [тут](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-wcf-services-through-asp-net-and-dotvvm-a-step-by-step-guide/) вы получите соединение

или проделав тоже самое в обычном консольном приложении моно подключиться к службе
и попробовать выполнить примерный код

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PartsRemainsClient client = new PartsRemainsClient();

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
}
```